# npm install results in network connectivity error: npm ERR! cb() never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I got an error when I execute `npm install`.

See error below:

```
71 error code ETIMEDOUT
72 error errno ETIMEDOUT
73 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fanimations failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.112.162:443
74 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
74 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
74 error network
74 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
74 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
75 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I switched to different Wifi connections and verified no proxy is configured, but I still get the same error message.

See package.json below:

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

The application is a working application and I am just trying to get it working on my local machine.

EDIT:

After disabling the firewall, I am facing another issue:
npm ERR! cb() never called!

```
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-15T13_53_25_178Z-debug.log
```

See log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli 'install',
1 verbose cli '-g',
1 verbose cli 'npm@latest' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v9.3.0
4 verbose npm-session ab5aa101dc35bd1a
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 error cb() never called!
8 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
9 error https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
```

Comment: where did you try to execute this?

Comment: Inside GIT repository of the web interface. FYI: package.json does exist.

Comment: please share the contents of your package.json

Comment: This is the reason why you need deterministic way to manage dependencies like yarn

Comment: @2oppin Added package.json above.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my previous answer about "typo" is wrong, not in your case.
Your package.json absolutely correct, but error you have is in the internet connection.

You or have no internet or under the proxy, anyway your request didn't reach npmjs.org
try to access https://registry.npmjs.org/ in the browser
or "*telnet registry.npmjs.org 443*" in the console
to ensure, then google why you can't reach some resource "***", how to setup proxy, etc. depending on your case.

Comment: It is actually `"@angular/animations": "^4.2.4"` inside the package.json.

Comment: @MuttalipKucuk, yupp, check internet connection then), then try browser, telnet,.. so your trouble is not in npm, but in a network setup

Comment: @2opping I can reach https://registry.npmjs.org/ on my browser. I disable the firewall, now I am facing the error "npm ERR! cb() never called!". For more info, see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19751

Comment: @MuttalipKucuk, seems you have several node.js installations. npm log shows that it useed 9x, and your local shows 8x. I'd try to reinstall npm, or even node. latest one already goes with npm.